# Restrict access to service-connections/agent-pools and git repos using CLI

Tags: azure-devops

I'm currently trying to automate the setup process of our MS Azure environments that integrate with our git and pipelines in Azure DevOps. So far we've done this manually by manually restricting access to service connections and agent pools when a new project is created, but this takes time and is rather error prone during the setup process, which leads to other issues down the line. I'm trying to automate the security configuration using the `az devops` cli, but after reading through the documentation I haven't been able to see anything clear about how this can be done using the CLI. To be clear I'm trying to use the CLI to:

- Remove inherited permissions at both project and organization levels for service connections and agent pools
- Manage specific allow/deny permissions for project git repositories as pictured below (and similarly for pipelines):

[image]

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi CPerkins, any update?

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I'll be able to test this today, but I think I'm going to need to figure out an issue I've been having with authorization. I tried to run the reset permissions command while I was first testing, and it said that an ID I didn't recognize wasn't authorized to do that. I assumed that it was my credentials from `az login` that were used, and I have administrator on the project in question. I'll report back when I've tried this out further.

Comment: I'm still working on this. So far I haven't been able to get anything to run due to permissions. For example the permission reset command says my user doesn't have access, even though I am an Administrator on the project level. Do you happen to know if it's necessary to have administrator at the organization level?

Answer (score 0):

> Remove inherited permissions at both project and organization levels
> for service connections and agent pools

You can use this cli to reset the permission of user/group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-permission-reset-all

> Manage specific allow/deny permissions for project git repositories as
> pictured below (and similarly for pipelines):

In DevOps Cli, only one type of command can achieve this.

For example, if you want to restrict service connection access.

If you run `az devops security permission namespace list --org https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP` then you will get all the namespace id, then you will find:

[image]

Run this command can deny:

`az devops security permission update --id 49b48001-ca20-4adc-8111-5b60c903a50c --subject xxx --token xxx --org https://dev.azure.com/yourorgname --deny-bit 30 --merge true --output table`

[image]

Refer to this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-permission-update

You can use the cli to manage permissions, but I highly recommend against doing so. cli settings are global and can be easily overridden by downstream permissions. And there is no method for a single project, it will lead to management confusion at some time.